# How to search text in the source files(include all javascript files) of a web page by using Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, text-search

How to search text in the source files(include all javascript files) of a web page by using Google Chrome?

If exist a Chrome Plugin, or show me how to list all javascript files a web page contains.

Google Chrome has a development tool that can be used to view source files and search within a specific file I point out, yet if the web page contains ***,*** files?
To search quickly, make a plugin!!!

Comment: Is "How to search text in the source files(include all javascript files) of a web page by using Google Chrome?" not a question? Really? 
Do you guys go around closing questions for fun? I want to know the answer to this too.

Comment: Here's is the answer in case anyone else needs it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/jpuwiYfRjf8%5B1-25%5D

Comment: ditto, please re-open

Comment: From within Develper Tools: Windows/Linux - press `Ctrl+Shift+F`; Mac - press `Cmd+Alt+F`